# Unable to lauch the IIS express Web Server - VS 2015

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm trying to debug a solution with Visual Studio 2015,i looked this error and tried everything i found but the error persist

- I started VS 2015 with Admin.
- I deleted the paste IISExpress and start VS again
- I change the "applicationhost" file inside the paste config (HTTP To HTTPS)
- I released in firewall issexpress.exe the connection
- Create another virtual Project and changed the port.

None os this worked,someone know other thing i could try?

---

Found the problem:

I deleted the file"applicationhost" inside \"Project".vs\config and when a openned my solution again it worked.